# Passing a function as a named argument for conditional checking

Tags: python, function, lambda, arguments

```
def basket(name, colour, smell, rotten=None):
    if rotten:
        if rotten():
            return "Can't eat!"

    return ("The fruit, {}, is {} in colour"
            "and smells like {}.".format(name, colour, smell))
```

In the example code above, the argument `rotten`, if provided, is checked before calling. It must be a function that returns a boolean (no arguments for simplicity). It consumes two lines of code and I'm not certain if this is the conventional style for this procedure. Another way I thought of doing it was to replace the current one with:

```
def basket(name, colour, smell, rotten=lambda: None):
    if rotten():  # Saved a line here
        return "Can't eat!"

    return ("The fruit, {}, is {} in colour"
            " and smells {}.".format(name, colour, smell))
```

The lambda method saves one line; apart from that I don't know which one has the advantage over the other. What is the preferable way of doing this? Is it found anywhere in the standard library code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave the function signature intact as in your first example and take advantage of [boolean operations's short circuit behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) to turn it into one line like this:

```
def basket(name, colour, smell, rotten=None):
    if rotten and rotten():
        return "Can't eat!"

    return ("The fruit, {}, is {} in colour"
            "and smells like {}.".format(name, colour, smell))
```

If `rotten` is `None`, the `and` expression will fail without calling `rotten()` because of short circuit. If `rotten` is not `None`, it will proceed to call `rotten()` and will succeed the predicate is `True`.

**Note:** As mentioned in the comments, you can also use the function [`callable()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=globals#callable) and check if `rotten` can be called before actually calling it:

```
if callable(rotten) and rotten():
```

This will protect your function from rising an exception when `rotten` is not `None` but is not a callable object (passing `rotten=True` for example). If otherwise you prefer the function to complaint out loud when a non callable is passed, then just let it as it is.

Comment: It might be better to write that as `if callable(rotten) and rotten():` so that it is assured that `rotten` is a function.  Otherwise, a user could make `rotten` something like `True` or `1` and get a `TypeError`.

Comment: I will include it as a side note in the answer, but maybe the OP prefer that when a non callable is passed, the function complaints out loud. That can be design dependent. Anyways thanks for the appreciation.

Comment: So, the lambda method proves to be of no particular benefit, eh? with lambda, I could perhaps change the default behavior by altering `lambda: None` to `lambda: True`, but I'm not sure if it is a pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to accomplish. You can keep the lambda version, IMHO it has no particular advantage over the other method. A function's user can still pass an invalid `rotten` and make the code fail. It's almost the same. I like the `rotten=None` approach because `None` is often used to show the absence of an argument with named parameters.

Comment: Beside, if you use `rotten=lambda: None`. You'll be using more memory (although not that much :) because the function will define the _default_ lambda and keep it through the end of the program. With `None`, this won't happen, since `None` object is globally referenced and already defined when the program begins.